# MSSQL/VB.NET INSERT DATA INTO TABLE WITH PROCEDURE

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am making a system that allows you to enter some data into a table. Some fields if the data may be null. The procedure returns a value that is of IDENTITY type. Below is the sub in use to enter the data using VB.NET:

```
Public Sub ownersWithReturn(ByVal fName As String)
        SqlConn.ConnectionString = Server
        Command = New SqlCommand()
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Command.CommandText = "EnterIntoPetOwners"
        Command.Parameters.Add("@ownername", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Clinician.txtOName.Text.Trim
        Command.Parameters.Add("@clinicno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Clinician.lblClinicNum.Text.Trim
        Command.Parameters.Add("@owneraddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Clinician.txtOAddress.Text.Trim
        Command.Parameters.Add("@insuno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Clinician.txtInsuNum.Text.Trim
        Command.Parameters.Add("@insudets", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Clinician.txtInsurDetails.Text.Trim
        Command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        Command.Connection = SqlConn
        Try
            SqlConn.Open()
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim id As String = Command.Parameters("@id").Value.ToString()
            Clinician.lblOwnerNum.Text = id
            Clinician.lblOwnerNum.ForeColor = Color.Black
            Dim result As Integer
            If result = 1 Then
                correctMes(1)
                nullControls(fName)
            Else
                errorMes(1)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            SqlConn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Below is the MSSQL PROCEDURE in use to insert the data:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EnterIntoPetOwners]
      @ownername VARCHAR(255),
      @clinicno INT,
      @owneraddress VARCHAR(500),
      @insuno INT,
      @insudets VARCHAR(500),
      @id int output
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO  Pet_Owners (Owner_Name,Clinic_No,Owner_Address,Insurance_No,Insurance_Details) 
      VALUES (@ownername,@clinicno,@owneraddress,@insuno,@insudets)
      SET @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
      RETURN  @id
END
```

The database variables that may be null are '`@insudets`' of data type VARCHAR and '`@insuno`' of data type INT.
When entering data using a form, when the two above mentioned fields are NOT null, no error occurs but when they are null and no data is availed, an error "`Failed to convert parameter value from a string to Int32`" shows.

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Looks like when you get a null value from your form field, you are sending an emtpy string as a parameter to your stored procedure. You should send null, not an empty string , they are totally different : ("@insuno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Clinician.txtInsuNum.Text.Trim ) . This seems to be the problem to me .

Comment: You shouldn't return `@id`. Setting its value when it is an `OUTPUT` parameter is all you need. `RETURN` is meant to communicate status of execution - success or fail for instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to insert a NULL value in the database you pass the DBNull.Value for that parameter. According to your code it seems that if the two textboxes are empty you want to set the matching fields to null. In this case you check and select the value that you want to insert

```
Dim insuno = IF(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Clinician.txtInsuNum.Text),
                DBNull.Value, Clinician.txtInsuNum.Text.Trim)
Dim insudets = IF(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Clinician.txtInsurDetails.Text),
                DBNull.Value, Clinician.txtInsurDetails.Text.Trim)

....

Command.Parameters.Add("@insuno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = insuno
Command.Parameters.Add("@insudets", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = insudets
```

Without this check the empty string goes to the database engine that tries to convert it to a number. This triggers the exception because an empty string cannot be converted to an integer